# Zend mod rewrite not working

Tags: zend-framework

Zend mod rewrite seems to be not working. `mysite/index.php/controller/action` works, so it must be the mod-rewrite. I verified using the phpinfo that it is loading.

Here is my `.htacess` file:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Is your .htaccess being called?  Check in the main apache config that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` for this vhost.