# how to configure htaccess in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I cannot access other modules(pages). I can access only public directory http://localhost:88/hotelrwanda/public. I put the project into development mode and enable error 
display but nothing. Here is what message I get if I want to access to for the following url http://localhost:88/hotelrwanda/public/users/list

Not Found

The requested URL /hotelrwanda/public/users/list was not found on this server.

Here is my htaccess file;

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you guys help me out. I cannot post any question. I need you your help

Comment: I don't think you will get any answers to this question, there is a lot of information missing and by the nature of your question i'm guessing you should start here : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Can you help to make it an banned. I cannot ask any question, Could you please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Zend mod rewrite not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054214/zend-mod-rewrite-not-working)

I believe the issue is that `AllowOverride` is set to `none` for the web directory you are using which means the `.htaccess` file will not be processed.  You will have to edit `httpd.conf` and set `AllowOverride All`.

Also make sure you create a Bootstrap file for each module, as the autoloading is not set up for modules unless you have a module bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you, The problem was that `AllowOverride` was set `none`