# 404 on new controller in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have created a new controller using

```
zf Create Controller About
```

but when I try to navigate to the path(http://mysite.com/about) I get a  404. Below are the details

site is setup at
C:\apache\htdocs\mysite.com\public

I have modified the vhosts file(C:\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf) to add virtual host like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/apache/htdocs/mysite.com/public"
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mysite-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Also added a mapping to windows hosts file like
127.0.0.1    mysite.com

here is my .htaccess file from public folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I can access http://mysite.com but when I try to access http://mysite.com/about I get a 404.

In my httpd.conf I have the following

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: figured out..had to enable mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting such detailed configuration information.

You need to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` within the `<Directory "C:/apache/htdocs">` block.

When AllowOverride is `None`, this means the .htaccess file is not processed, and therefore your URL rewriting to Zend Application's front controller does not take place.

See also: [how to configure htaccess in zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260795/how-to-configure-htaccess-in-zend-framework/10264503#10264503)

Comment: thanks:) and this too is required.

Comment: if possible it's good to move rewrite rules to `httpd.conf` in this case you don't even need `.htaccess` file